# No notifications loaded on meta?

Tags: support

Hope this fits to meta.

At other SE sites I get notificated if there are events concerning me or new questions. For example on scifi.SE I do get them periodically. Here on Arqade I don't get anything - no new questions, no notification bar reloaded.

[image]
*Example of notification on scifi.SE*

**Is it just me or are notifications deactivated on Arqade?**

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same feature is active here, both on meta and main site. Just make sure you're sorting by newest or active to see it relatively often.

[image: 1 question with new activity]

Comment: Okay thanks, so it is me. Yes, I'm sorting it that way, but I don't get any reloads. I have to do this always manually. Does it conflict when I have two SE sites open at once?

Comment: It shouldn't conflict at all. I always have main and meta + MSO open.

Comment: Well ok... are there other known problems why this only occurs to me on Arqade?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. Perhaps someone else knows and notices the question.